# How Do I open QT Designer after installing PYQT5 on a macbook pro?

Tags: macos, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Hello I installed pyqt5 using homebrew. And I have been able to create gui using hard coding only using python 3.6 IDLE but I want be able to open QT Designer as well to help save time and learn. Ive been searching for about a week and I cant figure out how to open qt designer. Please help. thank you.

Comment: Doesn't OSX have [Finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)) for opening applications?

Comment: Maybe it does not include the standalone designer, because the QtCreator does include it/the functionality?

Comment: Im able to use pyqt5 within my pyton IDLE but when i open up QT Creator the deisgn feature does not show and it doesnt show the UI file. here is a screenshot https://prnt.sc/goufr0

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the QtDesigner or QtCreator (has the designer included) installed, you can install QtCreator via the package for Qt5 that is available for macos on the [Qt download page](https://www1.qt.io/download-open-source/)

Comment: Thanks I already installed pyqt5 using homebrew. Im able to make a window / buttons using python idle but when I open qt creator the design feature is not available. Here a screenshot https://prnt.sc/goufr0

Comment: In the menu: File->Add new or similar. In the dialog it opens should be the a entry for it (I think it is called UI class or design.). It is definitely there.

Comment: For generating code you need:`pyuic5 xyz.ui > xyz.py `. QtCreator generates c++ code for the ui files.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded pyqt5 using home brew, pyqt5 tools and designer should have been installed automatically with it on a Mac. Navigate to your Bin folder and QT designer should be there.